# JQuery Click Function Randomly Stops Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I am sorting a list of users by first name when a user click on the sort  icon. However, I've noticed that there are times when I click the sort icon, the icon is switched, however, the data not sorted. For example, I click on it 10 times, and there may be 3 times when the data simply not sorted but the icon changed. Any help here would be appreciated.

**A partial section of the html code.**

```
  <div class="divFullWidth hidden-sx col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
<a href="#" data-action="POST"> First Name</a> 
<a id="sortName" href="#" data-sort="SORT">
<i id="sortIcon" class="sort fa fa-1x fa-sort-alpha-desc"></i></a></div>
```

**The function to handle replacing the button and submit the form.**

```
  $('#sortName').on('click', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         if ($('#sortIcon').hasClass('fa-sort-alpha-desc')) {
             $('#searchVal').val('asc');
             $('form').submit();
             $(this).find('#sortIcon').removeClass('fa-sort-alpha-desc').addClass('fa-sort-alpha-asc');
         } else {
             $('#searchVal').val('desc');
             var myVal = $('#searchVal').val();
             $('form').submit();
             $(this).find('#sortIcon').removeClass('fa-sort-alpha-asc').addClass('fa-sort-alpha-desc');
         }
     });
```

Comment: Are you sure the page really reloads on each click. I would guess that sometimes the request takes to much time and you trigger another request when you click the sort.

Comment: I thought about that too, so I waited as long as 30 seconds before doing a second click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code to see if the hidden field is null or not. Then, I made a decision based on that decision. The new JQuery code is below, and it's worked fine so far.

```
 $('#sortName').on('click', function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             var testVal = $('#searchVal').val();
             if (testVal === 'desc') {
                 $('#sortIcon').removeClass('fa-sort-alpha-desc').addClass('fa-sort-alpha-asc');
                 $('#searchVal').val('asc');
             } else {
                 $('#sortIcon').removeClass('fa-sort-alpha-asc').addClass('fa-sort-alpha-desc');
                 $('#searchVal').val('desc');
             }
             $('form').submit();
         });
```

Answer (score 3):

Is the following line suppose to be the same in both the if block and the else block?

```
$(this).find('#sortIcon').removeClass('fa-sort-alpha-desc').addClass('fa-sort-alpha-asc');
```

Comment: I know that you where not able to create a comment at the time you created this answer and I didn't down-vote cause of that. But as soon as you can write comments, then you shouldn't add such a question in the answer section.

Comment: Thanks, I realized that and updated the code. I was doing $('#sortIcon').removeClass('fa-sort-alpha-desc').addClass('fa-sort-alpha-asc'), but I swithed to $(this).find(). I forgot to replaced the desc after I copy the code to the else statement.

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this

```js
$('a#sortName').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Setting the current clicked icon into a variable.
    var findSortIcon = $(this).find('#sortIcon');
    if (findSortIcon.hasClass('fa-sort-alpha-desc')) {
        $('#searchVal').val('asc');
        //$('form').submit(); - We are sending the submit anytime whenever the button is   clicked
        findSortIcon.removeClass('fa-sort-alpha-desc').addClass('fa-sort-alpha-asc');
    } else {
        $('#searchVal').val('desc');
        //var myVal = $('#searchVal').val(); - no need for this (You dont use it anyway)
        // $('form').submit(); - same in here
        findSortIcon.removeClass('fa-sort-alpha-asc').addClass('fa-sort-alpha-desc');
    }
    // Whether its true or false submit it!
    $('form').submit();
    
    
    // Extra stuff to check changing directly
    var attr = findSortIcon.attr("class");
    $('#show-class').html(attr + " for " + $(this).text())
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divFullWidth hidden-sx col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
  <a href="#" data-action="POST"> First Name</a> 
  <a id="sortName" href="#" data-sort="SORT">
    <i id="sortIcon" class="sort fa fa-1x fa-sort-alpha-desc">
      ICON
    </i>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="divFullWidth hidden-sx col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
  <a href="#" data-action="POST"> First Name2</a> 
  <a id="sortName" href="#" data-sort="SORT"> 
    <i id="sortIcon" class="sort fa fa-1x fa-sort-alpha-desc">
      ICON2
    </i>
  </a>
</div>

<div id="show-class"></div>
```

Comment: I tried your code, and it work as well. Why does it work when a variable is created but does not work when no variable is created?

Comment: It's not the variable I check also in the `if()` for `$(this).find('#sortIcon')` for searching inside "that" area and you did the check like `if($('#sortIcon'.....)` that will check only for the first . You need to check "the clicked" area.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code instead:

```
$('#sortName').on('click', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     if ($('#sortIcon').hasClass('fa-sort-alpha-desc')) {
         $(this).find('#sortIcon').removeClass('fa-sort-alpha-desc').addClass('fa-sort-alpha-asc');
         $('#searchVal').val('asc');
     } else {
         $(this).find('#sortIcon').removeClass('fa-sort-alpha-asc').addClass('fa-sort-alpha-desc');
         $('#searchVal').val('desc');
     }
     $('form').submit();
 });
```

Comment: Because you changed so much of the code, you should explain what you changed and why it should solve the problem.